# Using Tchart in c++ to draw a vertical line

Tags: c++, teechart, diagramming

I got some values that i need to draw as a vertical line. The line should be from begin till the end of diagramm field.

I use VCLTee.Chart.hpp in Embarcadero. As I know it is the Tchart, that is actually used more for Delphi.

However:

I use this function:

```
DlgMainWindow->ChartTemperatureCurve->Canvas->DoVertLine(XValue,YValue,ZValue);
```

i can´t find the description. As I see DoVertLine works with Pixel of the diagramm. But if my YValue = 10 , and should be always parallel to x for whole distance.

Comment: how to draw a constant verticle line in embarcadero with c++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should convert your YValue from axis values to pixels with the axis `CalcPosValue` function.

If you want to draw a line at a constant YValue, it would be an **horizontal** line, not a vertical line.

In the following example I'm drawing an horizontal line at YValue=10.
Note the drawing functions should be called at `OnAfterDraw` event or similar to make sure your custom drawings are done after every repaint.

To use `OnAfterDraw` event on *RAD Studio*, select the chart at design-time, navigate to the *Events* tab at the *Object Inspector* and double-click on the white cell next to `OnAfterDraw`.
This action should open the code view with the cursor inside a new and empty OnAfterDraw function.
Then you can add what you want to do there. Ie, drawing an horizontal line within the `ChartRect`, at YValue=10:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Chart1AfterDraw(TObject *Sender)
{
  Chart1->Canvas->Pen->Color = clRed;

  int X0Pos = Chart1->ChartRect.Left;
  int X1Pos = X0Pos + Chart1->ChartRect.Width();
  double YVal = 10;
  int YPos = Chart1->Axes->Left->CalcPosValue(YVal);

  Chart1->Canvas->DoHorizLine(X0Pos, X1Pos, YPos);
}
```

Comment: yeah sry , actually i meant horizontal, but my head is empty

Comment: Using it in a thread, i put your function in synchronize. There is a dynamic curve and this horizontal. it draws once and than disappear. what could be the reason?

Comment: Note custom drawing functions must be called at OnAfterDraw or similar; inside an event that is being called after each repaint. Otherwise the next repaint will overwrite what you've manually drawn.

Comment: I've edited the answer explaining you how to use OnAfterDraw event